# $(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q)$ converting to sentence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Well, I am following this video lecture (MOOC) and I came across this quiz where I have to convert $(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q)$  to sentence.

$Q$: "I will go to town"

$R$: "I have time"

My answer to $(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q)$  is

"I will go to town ONLY IF I have time AND I have time ONLY IF I will go to town".

Whereas, the professor teaching in video gave following answer:

"I will go to town ONLY IF I have time AND IF I have time I will go to town".

I don't get the answer given by professor because it changes the meaning of sentence after 'AND'.

NOTE: Further professor explain that this can be converted to equivalent "If and Only If", but my concern is not on equivalence. I understand that part.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: "If x, then y" is equivalent to "x only if y". Both mean $x\rightarrow y$.

Comment: You're both right and I think your professor would agree. A problem with MOOC (as I understand it) is that there's less room for ask or discussing these things with your professor.

Comment: @Riley but Prof. hasn't use the form "If x, then y".

Comment: Yes he did. "If I have time I will go to town."

Comment: @Riley you are correct. I searched further and found that prof. is correct (and so as you). I searched further [here](https://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/logic/logic3.html) on net and found that Professor is correct. She used, "q if r" means r→q (2nd condition after AND) for "I will go to town IF I have time", but wrote it other way round.